# Someone broke my question formatting?

Tags: support, edits

I have this question in SE: [undefined reference to `bfd_get_section_by_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290755/undefined-reference-to-bfd-get-section-by-name)

I see an edit was made to it by someone else. Now when I try to save it, without changes I get:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

It doesn't tell me what line is the error. Why am I getting an error after someone else edited my question?

Answer (score 2):

I rolled back the edit.

---

I'm not totally sure about the implementation, nor you offer what was what you were trying to change/add, but the probability that it was the gcc/ld error that was triggering the check.

Both revisions were difficult to read/parse, since you used the quote syntax instead of code blocks. Now everything that should have a code block has it. Unless you are quoting someone don't use the quote syntax.

Comment: I recommend the quote syntax for 1 line errors: it allows for correct indexing with Stack Overflow's ElasticSearch configuration.

Comment: @Cœur which then breaks the very helpful formatting of error messages that interpreters and compilers have.